# YouTube Authentication stopped working

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

We're using oauth2 authetication for devices in order to allow our app to upload videos to YouTube accounts. This has been working fine for a number of weeks, but when I tried to authorise an account today, when I enter the phase where we poll for a token by calling https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token it now returns 428 Precondition required.

I can only find a vague description of this in the global Google API docs. We haven't changed any code so unless Google have changed something at their end, I don't understand why this is suddenly no longer working.

Has anyone else had this issue recently and if you have, do you know of a solution?

Many thanks,

Damien

Comment: Did you try debugging, like create new credentials, access tokens?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. Yes I did debug it and the authentication tokens are correct.

After some experimentation, I've found that what's happening is that the API response for the polling for token call is now returning http status code 428 instead of 400 (for situations where the user hasn't accepted access yet and where the response would be authorization_pending). If I handle this code in the same way as a 428 it all works without problem.

Not sure why Google are now doing this as it can potentially break a lot of apps, but if anyone else is having this issue, you just need to check for code 428 instead.